# nohup create new files nohup.out by day

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

I don't know if I can do it with nohup, but this is the question.... I have this command:

```
nohup java -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -Xmx2048M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=dump.hprof -jar $iscsiJar &
```

and I want that when the day change I save the before day nohupYYYYMM01.out and create another file nohupYYYYMM02.out , of course, with out kill my process. =)

Is it possible, how do I program it in shell script?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Just use `logrotate` for this.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure `java` is smart enough to start logging to a different file when requested by `logrotate`, unless it's configured to restart the program, which seems to be unacceptable to OP...

Comment: There is a `copytruncate ` option in logroate that **Truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one. It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever.**

Comment: @anubhava Right, and that's part of the equation, but I've also seen that result in sparse files because the write offset doesn't get updated in the parent process when the file is truncated. That may be acceptable, though, and I don't recall under exactly what conditions that occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one solution for this is using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

Below a example of /etc/supervisord.conf

```
...
[program:coherence]
command=java -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -Xmx2048M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=dump.hprof -jar $iscsiJar &
directory=/u01/jdk
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/var/log/java.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/java.out.log
user=oracle
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

Using supervisord you can stop/start this *process* like was a service.

Comment: nice, thanks. I did this simple configuration with testSupervisor.sh and it works. now I am gonna try with java

[program:testSupervisor]
command=/root/testSupervisor.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=3KB
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=3KB
stderr_logfile=/root/err.log
stdout_logfile=/root/out.log

Comment: Hi, How do I set the limit of open files to the supervisord?

Comment: never mind, I found here http://blog.cesarcd.com/2014/10/connectionerror-too-many-open-files-in.html