# Supervisord and ulimit to java app

Tags: java, supervisord, ulimit

I am using supervisord to start my java app. The application is working OK, but my ulimit nofiles is not set. I could do it in one machine, using debian. but there is a problem on the second machine that this configuration is not working. Basically, I start my app with a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

iscsiJar="/mnt/cache/jscsi/udrive.jar"

ulimit -SHn 32768

# função para iniciar a aplicação
java -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -Xmx2048M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=dump.hprof -jar $iscsiJar
```

But my command cat /proc/4171/limits keeps saying:

Max open files            4096                 4096                 files

Any hint? I already search everywhere at internet.... I could try this way on this question> [nohup create new files nohup.out by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449372/nohup-create-new-files-nohup-out-by-day)

Comment: I'm suspecting the supervisord configuration to start the application with another user since when I start the app some directories are being created as root.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still looking for a solution for that, try setting: **minfds** parameter within supervisord configuration file:
http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-values

Remember to restart the supervisord after configuration change.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solutions writing another java program Test with the supervisor. I also used `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` and my linux user was not configured properly.

I also used [this answer from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/317153/allow-all-users-of-a-group-to-start-and-stop-zope-using-supervisorctl) to help me.